# Webpage with several countdown timers

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am showing objects from a MySQL database in a website.
Each object has a deadline datetime field (called termina).
I have a while loop to show each item:

```
<?php
global $mysqli;
$loop = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sub.titulo AS titulo, 
    sub.referencia AS referencia,
    sub.descripcion AS descripcion,
    make.name AS marca,
    model.name AS modelo,
    gen.name AS generacion,
    serie.name AS serie,
    mot.name AS motor,
    sub.foto AS foto,
    sub.termina AS termina,
    sub.id_subasta AS id_subasta
    FROM tb_subastas sub 
    LEFT JOIN car_make make ON sub.marca = make.id_car_make
    LEFT JOIN car_model model ON sub.modelo = model.id_car_model
    LEFT JOIN car_generation gen ON sub.generacion = gen.id_car_generation
    LEFT JOIN car_serie serie ON sub.serie = serie.id_car_serie
    LEFT JOIN car_trim mot ON sub.motor = mot.id_car_trim")
or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
$orden = 0;
$resultado = $loop ->num_rows;

if ($resultado == 0){

    ?>  <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">


                    <p>NO HAY SUBASTAS</p> 


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
{

    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <H3><?php echo $row['titulo']?></H3> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <H2 >Ref.: <?php echo $row['referencia']?></H2>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <p><?php echo $row['descripcion']?></p> 
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">

                    <p><strong>Marca: </strong><?php echo $row['marca']?></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">

                    <p><strong>Modelo: </strong><?php echo $row['modelo']?></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">

                    <p><strong>Generación: </strong><?php echo $row['generacion']?></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">

                    <p><strong>Serie: </strong><?php echo $row['serie']?></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">

                    <p><strong>Motor: </strong><?php echo $row['motor']?></p> 
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: black">

                    <img  style="width: 100%;height: auto;align-self: " src=".../<?php echo $row['foto']?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
<p><strong>Termina: </strong><?php echo $row['termina']?></p> 



<style>

 #clockdiv<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#clockdiv<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?> > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}
#clockdiv<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?> div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}
smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>">
  <div>
    <span class="days<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>" id="day<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>" id="hour<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>" id="minute<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>" id="second<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="demo<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>"></p>

<script>
 var deadline=0;

var deadline = new Date("<?php echo $row['termina']?>").getTime();
 //alert(deadline);
var x = setInterval(function() {

var now = new Date().getTime();
var t = deadline - now;
var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
document.getElementById("day<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML =days ;
document.getElementById("hour<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML =hours;
document.getElementById("minute<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML = minutes; 
document.getElementById("second<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML =seconds; 
if (t < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML = "TIME UP";
        document.getElementById("day<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML ='0';
        document.getElementById("hour<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML ='0';
        document.getElementById("minute<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML ='0' ; 
        document.getElementById("second<?php echo $row['id_subasta']?>").innerHTML = '0'; }
}, 1000);
</script>







                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="CREAR NUEVA SUBASTA" onclick="location.href = 'ficha_subasta.php';"> 
                </div>

            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I want to show the object as following screenshot:

[image]

The issue is that all countdown timer show the same remaining time, but they should be different.

I cannot find out the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, currently you are sharing a common deadline with all loops.

1. You need to move update time JavaScript out of current loop
2. Add seperate loop inside setInterval function on all timers to their individual termina using hidden fields of each termina record

Comment: would you mind to give me another explanation? I don't see what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have solved it putting var deadline = new Date("<?php echo $row['termina']?>").getTime(); inside setinterval function.